# Oreo Background Services

Tags: android, background-process, android-8.0-oreo, foreground-service

Within our application we use multiple Services and Intent Services for BLE communication, microphone recording, etc.

We have noticed the newly Background Limitations and Restrictions (Yes, we did notice it rather late, I know). I've changed the implementations for using ContextCompat.startForegroundService() function and using the startForeground() with a notification like it stated in the docs.

But we saw that when the application is **killed**, the Foreground Service dies also after a few minutes. Should it happen? Should the Foreground Service will only continue to work if the app is in the **background**?

Also, if this is the case what does the Battery Optimization feature do? Keeps the Service working while in background only? Can the Service still be killed while the app is the background with this feature on?

I've read a lot of docs regarding it but I'm still confused regarding the state of Service when the application is **killed**.

We do not mind showing a notification for those services but we still want  it to continue to work "endlessly".

Comment: What do you mean by "killed"? Removed from Recents? That shouldn't stop the Service. Force Stopped? Of course that will stop the Service.

Comment: Yes, I meant by Remove from Recents.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler is the only option left.

Comment: @MartinZeitler nonsense

Comment: even if the App is removed from recents, the foreground service still works... the fg service can only be stopped either you have an option in your app, or if the user force stops your app or the system terminates the service if it needs space (resources)!

Comment: @TimCastelijns what should be the alternatives to it?

Comment: @MartinZeitler nothing. Jobscheduler is not an alternative for a service

Comment: @DarShan, can it be specific for an Android device? I'm testing it on OnePlus 6. I can't test it on Emulator. Also, It may be to my fault and not implement it correctly. I'll double-check again.

Comment: @Gil nope, same for all

Comment: @TimCastelijns of course it is not the same, nevertheless one can still schedule the execution of jobs, based upon conditions, alike connectivity change, content provider changes or when the device starts charging the battery.

Comment: @DarShan Thanks a lot. I'll try and manage to find a WORKING example.

Comment: @DarShan, I see someone just wrote this - if `(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE));
    mNotificationManager.startServiceInForeground(new Intent(this, BaseOverlayService.class), NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
} else {
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}`, Is this the right way for start in foreground for Oreo? I simply user startForeground, maybe that my problem?

Comment: @Gil startForeground()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But we saw that when the application is killed, the Foreground Service dies also after a few minutes. Should it happen? Should the Foreground Service will only continue to work if the app is in the background?

Yes it destroys foreground service.., But it recreates again within the microseconds... Its natural behaviour. Even if you killed app by swiping it away from recent apps..!!

Post your foreground service code only..!! with no extra code and i will correct it so that it can behave the way i stated..

> Also, if this is the case what does the Battery Optimization feature do? Keeps the Service working while in background only? Can the Service still be killed while the app is the background with this feature on?

If battery is optimising then it might not re launch your foreground service too ON_BOOT_COMPLETE

> I've read a lot of docs regarding it but I'm still confused regarding the state of Service when the application is killed.

Yes, i know it is total waste of time as google documentation is having no straight forward ways in documenting and there are no sample codes for developers... If you wants to code for more than 4 android os then all codes needed to coded as per version codes..!!

> We do not mind showing a notification for those services but we still want it to continue to work "endlessly".

It never happens... ENDLESSLY must be implemented with the broadcastreceivers as and and when you wants your services can seem to be running endlessly.. Again you can not create static receivers and can not call them via manifest as before...  You need to create it from a foreground service in runtime.

> Where i can get example codes?
>   No where... Google has no sample codes... just blah blah blah...
>
> Short and sweet... I had lost my complete year and now well known about all above your questions and have implemented it in apps and apps are in market running quite good as expected... And i like to help them all as google lacks it in documentation.. Post your code , Let me know, and Get it worked from me

---

### Edit : 2

Google has made `wrong os` ( Android ) based on `wrong concept` with `wrong implementation` with `wrong support` with `wrong documentation` with `wrong License` which is open source which allows `non - standard` companies to modify and use it.. Now Consider its dis-advantages :

1. It frustrates developers to code an app which even supports for more than one version.. Say `Lollipop` and `Marshmallow`. Both ways are different and already developer has 1000 cases to handle and then again this..
2. Case becomes worst to develop when it comes to develop more than 2 versions at a time... Its a complete mess..
3. Again google keep changing rules over few months of time...
4. With no proper documentation makes developers only one option open is to pull the hairs out..!!
5. These all was not sufficient ..., so again :-

Vivo : `ColorOs`
OnePlus : `OxygenOs`
MI : `FunTouchOs`
.
.
.
.

This is huge list of companies who does not know how to modify ( and why to modify...? ) started modifying `stock-android`.., most of which only allows `facebook`, `Google`, `Whatsapp`, `Instagram`, major social app vendors services only to come in memory on `Boot_complete`.

> Why only these services and why not mine..?

Because buyers wont buy a phone on which above softwares will not work..!! No one will take such phones..!!

> Why not mine..?

This is a business

> Is there any other way...?

No way..!! As we develop apps standardly on Googles Android Studio and also tests it on emulators of google which holds stock-android systems..!! So don't guranty will it work on every manufacturers device or not..!!

> Who is responsible for these all situations.. and what is solution..?

Google is responsible for these all frustrations and all the mobile phone manufactures has taken it the such extent which is now impossible to handle.. Google has to come with restriction on modifications and also hardware support systems must be implemented..!! Best way to dis-continue such unmanaged operating system.

Comment: It actually looks to works quite OK on Samsung S9 (Even if I kill my app the foreground Service continue to work), but on my OnePlus 6, the OS happens to kill my Service, even If I remove the battery optimization switch for my app. It looks as Oxygen OS working quite differently than others. I suspect it may be related to specific devices/manufacturers  only. Did any of you seems to came across this issues on other devices?

Comment: Thanks for the your sincere comment. It seems that there's no other solution rather than send the user to Battery settings and make our app not optimized for battery improvements. Leaving you with such a bad taste after this Oreo update, it so awefule that Google mimics Apple in a half-baked feature.

Comment: Exactly. Frustrating. Even after battery settings your app still can't survive.