# AlarmManager firing in emulator but not on physical Oreo device

Tags: android, alarmmanager, background-process

We are running some alarm services in the background and it's working in Oreo emulator, but on a real device it is not working. Can anyone tell why my code fails?

```
val alarmIntent = Intent(this, NetworkChangeReceiver::class.java) 
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) 
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance() 
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1) 
val manager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager 
manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, 1000 * 60, pendingIntent)
```

another option is using work manager but it's working only every 15 min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background services it's not working in some devices like Vivo : ColorOs OnePlus : OxygenOs MI : FunTouchOs . . . .

```
More information check this below url.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52373492/7387028
```